# Which MinGW packages should I install?

Tags: c, mingw

I'm just starting to dip my toes on coding, starting with C. I asked people how to set an environment for C coding, they said VScode for editing and MinGW for compiling is the best.

I got VScode with C/C++ extension installed, but I have trouble installing MinGW. I've installed MinGW Installation Manager, and there are hundreds of packages available to download. Which of them should I install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [MinGW documentation](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW) about what packages are recommended. Also, the [free VisualStudio Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=16) might be better suited for beginners than MinGW, as it is an all-in-one-package.

Comment: Tried Visual Studio, felt like too many unwanted/unused programs were being installed with it. Will check out the documentation though. Thanks!